# How to retry a rejected promise inside Promise.all in real time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a file upload web app. I want to upload multiple files at the same time (5 for example) but when one of them fails I immediately show a RETRY button beside my file. When clicked I want it to retry its own Promise.

Regarding that I use Promise.all and all promises are inside Promise.all table how can I achieve that? I was thinking on using web workers but it seems too much for such a task.

Here's a snippet of code that I'm using (two files case):

```
await Promise.all([promise1.done(), promise2.done()]);
```

Comment: What is `.done()`? Standard promises have no such method.

Comment: it's a aws upload i just named it promise1 / 2 in fact it's name is parallelUploads3

Comment: Don't use `Promise.all` at all. What code comes after the `await`? In React.Js, explicitly model the state of the uploads in your component, and render your buttons accordingly.

Comment: what comes after the await is a chekc if upload is done i set the UploadState to false just to indicate that we're not  uploading (upload done)

Comment: Yes, but since you want to do that individually for each upload now, not for all of them together, you don't need that any more. You should do `upload1done().then(setUpload1Success, setUpload1Error); upload2done().then(setUpload2Success, setUpload2Error);`

Comment: will this solution be executed in parallel ?

Comment: Yes, it would still start all uploads at once, having them run concurrently

Comment: okay thanks bro will give it a try and then see what will happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as *retrying a Promise*, because Promises do not keep their context. They are meant to change their status once and then they're unchangeable.

If you want to retry on failure, you'd need to explicitly call the action that resulted in your Promise again.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution as @RoboRobok and @Bergi said the solution was first (we can run parallel promises if we run them using promise.then ) and as @RoboRobok said we cannot reRun a failed promise instead we need to reproduce it again so what i did is creating a separated file called RetryUpload.js it has the code necessary to reproduce my Promise and that's all her's how i handled the promise (just for reference):

```
parallelUploads3
    .done()
    .then((success) => {
      .....
    })
    .catch((error) => {
     ....
    });
```